# Ruby - pick multiple max values from an array with their index

Tags: arrays, ruby, indexing, max

say that i have an
array = [22, 55, 55, 16]
I want to pick out the max values from the array along with their indexes.

Comment: What have you tried? Why didn't it work? How didn't it work? Did you get error, the wrong result, was the behavior unexpected? What did you try to fix it? Why, and in what way did your fix fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `max` to find max value and `index`/`rindex` or `select` to find indices depend on which kind of index do you need

```rb
array = [22, 55, 55, 16] 
max_val = array.max # 55
first_indedx = array.index(max_val) # 1 - first index
index = array.rindex(max_val) # 2 - last index
array.each_index.select{|i| array[i] == max_val} # [1, 2] - all indexes
```

You can find more details about methods here: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html

Answer (score 2):

To find the maximum values of an [`Enumerable`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html), there are the aptly named methods [`Enumerable#max`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-max) and [`Enumerable#max_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by).

Here is an example of using `Enumerable#max` (or more precisely, its overload [`Array#max`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-max)) to find the maximum value in your `array`:

```ruby
array.max
#=> 55
```

If you want more than one value, you can pass an [`Integer`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html) to `max` which will tell Ruby how many values you want:

```ruby
array.max
#=> 55

array.max(1)
#=> [55]

array.max(2)
#=> [55, 55]

array.max(3)
#=> [55, 55, 22]

array.max(4)
#=> [55, 55, 22, 16]

array.max(5)
#=> [55, 55, 22, 16]
```

So, now we know how to get an arbitrary number of maximum values. The only thing we are missing now, are the indices.

So, the first thing we are going to do, is to pair each value up with its index:

```ruby
array.each_with_index
#=> #<Enumerator: ...>
```

[`Enumerable#each_with_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) returns an [`Enumerator`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator.html), which pairs every element with its index. We can take a [peek](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator.html#method-i-peek) what that looks like:

```ruby
enum = array.each_with_index
#=> #<Enumerator: ...>

enum.peek
#=> [22, 0]
```

Or, we can look at the entire `Enumerator`, by using the [`Enumerable#to_a`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_a) method to convert it to an [`Array`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html):

```ruby
array.each_with_index.to_a
#=> [[22, 0], [55, 1], [55, 2], [16, 3]]
```

`Arrays` are lexicographically ordered, therefore, `Enumerable#max` will consider `[55, 2]` to be greater than `[55, 1]`:

```ruby
array.each_with_index.max
#=> [55, 2]

array.each_with_index.max(1)
#=> [[55, 2]]

array.each_with_index.max(2)
#=> [[55, 2], [55, 1]]

array.each_with_index.max(3)
#=> [[55, 2], [55, 1], [22, 0]]

array.each_with_index.max(4)
#=> [[55, 2], [55, 1], [22, 0], [16, 3]]

array.each_with_index.max(5)
#=> [[55, 2], [55, 1], [22, 0], [16, 3]]
```

If you are okay with preferring equal values that are at the end of the `array`, then we are done!

If you want to ignore the index when determining the maximum elements, we can use the `Enumerable#max_by` method, which allows us to pass our own criterion to determine the maximum. We can simply tell `Enumerable#max_by` to only use the first element by using the [`Array#first`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-first) method:

```ruby
array.each_with_index.max_by(&:first)
#=> [55, 1]

array.each_with_index.max_by(1, &:first)
#=> [[55, 1]]

array.each_with_index.max_by(2, &:first)
#=> [[55, 2], [55, 1]]

array.each_with_index.max_by(3, &:first)
#=> [[55, 2], [55, 1], [22, 0]]

array.each_with_index.max_by(4, &:first)
#=> [[55, 2], [55, 1], [22, 0], [16, 3]]

array.each_with_index.max_by(5, &:first)
#=> [[55, 2], [55, 1], [22, 0], [16, 3]]
```

And there you have it! The maximum `n` numbers, together with their indices.

Comment: wow. I learnt a lot from this. 
However, I'm really sorry that i didn't follow the community guidelines while asking the question. Because what I'm looking for is exactly what M116 has answered. I think I have been able to improve upon its length and have come up with:

  `max_values_index = arr.each_index.select do |index|`
   `arr[index] == arr.max`
  `end`

Now I'm unsure on how to go about editing the question so that it meets the guideline. Because I didn't have a clue as to how to solve this problem so easily. Only a vague idea that was clunky.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```rb
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> i = [22, 55, 55, 16]
irb(main):003:0> i.each_with_index { |n, index| puts "#{n}:#{index}" if n == i.max }

55:1
55:2
```

Comment: You are computing `n == i.max` for each element of `i`. That should only be done once.

Comment: thanks @CarySwoveland - with only 4 items in the array i ignored this, but you are right, it should only be computed once.